# Need more knowledge about strstr().It does not work for me

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.I store the tax detail in a session value to store whether the tax is inclusive or exclusive. And i need top check that string value using `strstr()` and do some calculation. I did the calculations bellow

```
<?php 
     $tax_percentage=$tax['company_tax13'];
    if(strstr($service_detail['service_tax'],"inclusive")==true) {
    $taxamount=$service_detail['service_price']-($service_detail['service_price']/(1+($tax_percentage/100)));
    $grand=$service_detail['service_price'];
    }
    else {
    $taxamount=($service_detail['service_price']*(1+($tax_percentage/100)))-$service_detail['service_price'];
    $grand=$taxamount+$service_detail['service_price'];
    }
    ?>
```

Response of my controller when I run the code is

```
Array ( [service_detail] => Array ( [service_price] => 1000 [service_tax] =>"inclusive" ) [tax] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [company_tax13] => 14 ) ) )
```

How could I code for this. Any problem with the code?
My controller file. Here I have a session variable that stores `service_detail['service_tax']`

```
 public function add()
    {
        //if save button was clicked, get the data sent via post
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        {
$this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('service_detail');
            //if the form has passed through the validation
            if ($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $data_to_store = array(
                'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                    'service_name' => $this->input->post('service_name'),
                    'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
                    'service_tax' => $this->input->post('service_tax'),
                    'service_length' => $this->input->post('service_length'),          
                    'service_price' => $this->input->post('service_price')
                );
                //if the insert has returned true then we show the flash message
                if($this->service_model->store_service($data_to_store)){
                    $data['flash_message'] = TRUE; 
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'updated');
                    $this->session->set_userdata('service_detail', ['service_price'=>$this->input->post('service_price'),'service_tax'=>$this->input->post('service_tax')]);
                    redirect(base_url().'admin/service/view');
                }else{
                    $data['flash_message'] = FALSE; 
                }

            }

        }
        $data['category'] = $this->category_model->get_category();
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/service/add';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
    }
```

Comment: why are you using `strstr()`?

Comment: to compare string that I receive.Is there some other way?

Comment: Try as `if(strpos($service_detail['service_tax'],"inclusive") > -1)`

Comment: Using this code I could see no change in my output.@Uchiha

Answer (score 1):

If your parameter is always `inclusive` / `exclusive` use a switch:

```
switch (strtolower($service_detail['service_tax']))
{
    case 'inclusive':
        //do your stuff;
        break;

    case 'exclusive':
        //do your stuff;
        break;
}
```

Comment: <?php 
    $tax_percentage=$tax[0]['company_tax13'];
    
    switch (strtolower($service_detail['service_tax']))
   {
       case 'inclusive':
           $taxamount=$service_detail['service_price']-($service_detail['service_price']/(1+($tax_percentage/100)));
       $grand=$service_detail['service_price'];
           break;

       case 'exclusive':
          $taxamount=($service_detail['service_price']*(1+($tax_percentage/100)))-$service_detail['service_price'];
       $grand=$taxamount+$service_detail['service_price'];
            break;
   }
    ?>

Comment: Is this ok? But i could not get my expected output

Answer (score 0):

In the view the $data array's keys are converted into variables, so try `var_dump($somekey)`. This is done with [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

You can also change `strstr` to `strcmp` or even `===` (since you are not concerned about which string is bigger).

```
if(strtolower($service_detail['service_tax']) === "inclusive")
```

or

```
if(strcmp(strtolower($service_detail['service_tax']), "inclusive"))
```

Comment: I am getting a blank screen using both code snippet.

Comment: Any problem with fetching the values inside array?

Comment: Yes, it's a fetch problem. I just tested with normal variables and worked fine. Let me improve my answer.

Comment: If you are doing it right (can you show Controller codes?), the array's keys are converted into variables: try var_dump($service_tax); for example.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please refer it and help me solve it

Comment: Sorry, I had to sleep. Simple try <?php var_dump($service_price); ?> into your view to check if the fetch is fine. If so, you can go ahead and change your previous view code.